# Recursively apply fold command linux to modify all files in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, recursion

I have this command line to modify the wrap of my files: 
    `fold -w 60 "$file"`
How can i recursively apply this command to all files in a directory and overwrite the existing contents of each file with the result from the command above?.

i found many very similar question, but all solutions offered involve concatenate the file to one file, which i don't need.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: try this ->`for i in $(find /<path-to-your-files-directory>/ -type f); do fold -w 60 $i > $i.temp; mv $i.temp $i ; done`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all I have found a way using the tip from @jayesh jodhawat

`for i in $(find . -type f); do fold -w 60 $i > $i.temp; mv $i.temp $i; done`

After navigating to the directory containing the files to transform.

Comment: please upvote and accept my answer if works :) @Anicet Ebou

Answer (score 0):

Try this bash script

```
for i in $(find /<path-to-your-directory>/ -type f); do fold -w 10 $i > $i.temp; mv $i.temp $i ; done
```

this will replace content in the same file recursively in the specified directory